# How to get the Arn of a resource created in a cdk script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm currently experimenting with AWS CDK and I'm stuck with something that, in my mind, should be easy.

(I'm working with python, but I believe it's the same with any "cdk enabled" language )

I can create a cognito UserPool (it works) :

```
    pool = cognito.CfnUserPool(self, "cdk_test_pool", 
        admin_create_user_config=cognito.CfnUserPool.AdminCreateUserConfigProperty(
            allow_admin_create_user_only=True
        ), 
        auto_verified_attributes=["email"], 
        policies=cognito.CfnUserPool.PoliciesProperty(
            password_policy=cognito.CfnUserPool.PasswordPolicyProperty(
                minimum_length=6, 
                require_lowercase=True, 
                require_numbers=True, 
                require_symbols=True, 
                require_uppercase=True
            )
        ), 
        user_pool_name="cdk_test_pool"
    )
```

An now I want to create an apigateway Authorizer, but I need the UserPool Arn :

```
    poolArn = ????????
    authorizer = apigateway.CfnAuthorizer(self, "cdk-test-authorizer",
        rest_api_id="hello-api", 
        type="COGNITO_USER_POOLS", 
        identity_source="method.request.header.Authorization", 
        name="cdk-test-authorizer", 
        provider_arns=[poolArn]
    )
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [Properties of the class CfnUserPool (construct)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cognito.CfnUserPool.html#properties), there is **attrArn**.

```
provider_arns=[
    pool.attr_arn
]
```

As you can see the documentation, there is no description about the property, and CDK and its documentation is at such level still. Please prepare defects, incorrect documentation, examples that do not work from CDK. It should be beta release.